# PHP Curl returns nothing, no error and no data

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to write a very simple PHP Curl script.

I used https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ to generate the PHP code

I input  curl www.example.com   and the resulting code was

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

I also added (prior to curl_close ($ch) )

```
print "<pre>";
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

The result was

```
Array
(
    [url] => HTTP://www.example.com/
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 338
    [request_size] => 54
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.172
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.078
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.078
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 1270
    [speed_download] => 7383
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 1270
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.172
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 93.184.216.34
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => 192.168.1.10
    [local_port] => 55774
)
```

I have tried this with a number of websites just using the basic URL with no parameters and get similar results, either [http_code] => 200 or [http_code] => 400

Is there something wrong with my server, the CURL-TO-PHP website or I am missing something else?

Comment: Trying taking a look at what’s in `$result` – that’s the page response.

Comment: if it a returned 200 OK status code then that means your request succeeded. But I don't see where in your code you're actually inspecting the body of the response to know if you've received any data or not? A 400 status means "Bad Request" of course, so it means the remote site didn't like your request for some reason. Again if you look in the response body you may find that a reason is given. In your code, you need to output the contents of `$result`

Comment: Whats not working? Not all sites allow bot requests hence [400](https://httpstatuses.com/400)..

Answer (score 0):

```
$result
```

Should have all the content of the page you fetched.

Also, if you get HTTP 400, they might be blocking these kinds of requests.
You can in that case try to send along a UserAgent with curl, something like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

That way you "fake" the useragent, like you are browsing through Chrome or Firefox, etc.

You can set that value to whatever you want, you can lookup the most common useragents

Comment: Thank you all - it is now working as expected.  I had failed to realise that the example code produced by curl-to-php did not add the output to the screen.